# What Language Is "Freeing The Essence Of Computing" Written In?

Tags: lisp, scheme

I found this article on partial evaluation which looked pretty cool: (the long link gives a HTML version) http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sZ6qu87l4u8J:openmap.bbn.com/~kanderso/performance/postscript/essence.ps+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

I thought I'd read it and run the code as I went along.  However, I could not get the code to run in either Racket Scheme or SBCL.

Is anyone familiar with this paper, and know what language it is written in?

Comment: Given the title, my guess is English :)

Comment: Looks like stock standard Scheme to me. What are you trying to run? Mostly papers just have *interesting* snippets and not full programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the text:

> Software examples are given in a Scheme like dialect of Common Lisp
>   where define replaces defvar, defun, and defmethod. While this may be
>   confusing to some, the idea is to keep the software abstract and free
>   of unnecessary detail, since the point is to show how such a language
>   can be easily and efficiently implemented. The ideas expressed here
>   should port to other languages as well, perhaps with a bit more work.

Sounds like the Dijkstra school. If you want practical books you can code along with, I'd suggest [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) or [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/). If you weren't past the basics, I'd also suggest the [Schemer Trilogy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992). Also, if you're ok with writing in non-Lisp languages, check out [Write Yourself a Scheme](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours).

Answer (score 1):

Another great book for LISPing is Paul Graham's *ANSI Common Lisp*, which has a title like a reference manual, but reads incredibly well. If you're absolutely sold, on implementing the abstract code, use [this](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/Contents.htm) to find rough (or fine) equivalents of the code and edit it for CL consumption.